# FastCGi process exited on IIS 10 PHP 8

Tags: runtime-error, odbc, fastcgi, iis-10, php-8

I've had this problem with my .php pages for a while now and have not found a solution online for PHP 8 on IIS.

I use Windows Server 2022, ISS 10, PHP 8, 12 GB RAM

The error occurs when I use my ODBC to fetch data from MS Access (i'm not hitting any limit on how much data I can retrieve). Other .php works when there is no SQL involved or a little of it. Now I can't even open up some of my .php web pages but 1/30 refresh-clicks and it works that one time.

The error is:

```
HTTP ERROR 500.0 - Internal Server Error.
C:/PHP/php-cgi.exe - The FastCGI process exited unexpectedly

Module             FastCgiModule
Notification       ExecuteRequestHandler
Handler            FastCGI
Error Code         0xc0000409
```

Event Viewer:

```
Faulting application name: php-cgi.exe, version: 8.2.6.0, time stamp: 0x645a702b
Faulting module name: ucrtbase.dll, version: 10.0.20348.1, time stamp: 0xdacb234c
Exception code: 0xc0000409
Fault offset: 0x000000000007ca9e
Faulting process id: 0x1228
Faulting application start time: 0x01d9d41c26d46113
Faulting application path: C:\PHP\php-cgi.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Windows\System32\ucrtbase.dll
Report Id: 4b3f87ee-78d2-4f9f-be73-63e6463e1ad5
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

FASTCGI settings on IIS. I have bumped up some values here and there, so some values have been lower with no success.

[image: CGI settings]

```
Queue Lenght: 10 000
Rapid Fails PerMinute: 10
Request Timeout: 600
Signal Before Terminate: 60
```

**WHAT HAS BEEN DONE:**

I have messed around with FastCGI settings in IIS.

Installed Visual Studio, don't know how many times

Have .NET v2 and v4.5

Using DefaultAppPool in IIS

Disabled CGI-exe and ISAPI-dll in Handler Mappings

Installed HTTP Activation for .NET Framework 4.8

Made a Request Failed Trace log on IIS where I can see FASTCGI assigns a process but FASTCGI_START is empty

[image]

**Thanks!**

**CONCLUSION**
Since it's hard to get a straight answer without doing some debugging myself, I'm going to try WinDbg as @Lex Li mentioned. Thanks for the effort everyone!

Comment: The Windows error code 0xC0000409 corresponds to STATUS_STACK_BUFFER_OVERRUN. This error typically indicates that there has been a buffer overrun, specifically related to the stack. Thus, the issue is either in your PHP code or PHP FastCGI process, not related to any IIS settings. Not a surprise if you are using certain technologies like Microsoft Access, which was not designed for web apps.

Comment: The 0xc0000409 error code can be caused by an incorrectly installed application. If this error code appears on your screen every time you try to launch a particular application, it is most likely due to some issues with the application. You can try uninstalling and reinstalling the app.

Comment: @LexLi I am certain the PHP code is not the issue since this problem is on multiple .php pages. Is it correct to say that FastCGI "crashes" when it's trying to retrieve data from Access? I don't think I have anything to say about changing MS Access. Is there any way to see how FastCGI behaves?

Comment: @YurongDai Since FastCGI comes with php I guess try to reinstall php. The best thing would be to replace only php-cgi.exe but I have not found any downloads for it on 8.2 version.

Comment: The weird thing is that now, when no-one has been on the server over night, it works like a charm when i'm using a .php page which retrieves a lot of data from MS Access. But I know that soon it will all come crashing down and be like that the rest of the day. (No one else is using this server yet since it's still in development)

Comment: The key to troubleshoot further is to learn how to debug native Windows memory issues with a debugger, and if you find that difficult to get started (quite normal) you might consider hiring someone. It is impossible to learn it quickly via discussions like this.

Comment: Thanks! @LexLi What program do you recommend to start with? I have looked through "Performace Monitor" (not the best way) and there I saw no spike in memory or such. Maybe there are some post on this forum that explains the way to use some debugging programs.

Comment: Professionals use tools like WinDbg. You can read about it and see how steep the learning curve is.